# JsTree Checkbox check Based on data-id

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jstree

I want to check unchecked checkbox in based on data-id.
On drop down change i want to check unchecked checkbox in jstree.
I am Providing MY controller and Ajax Method bellow.

This is my jstree view.[image]

Here is My Controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSingleUser(int id)
    {
        MachineShopDBEntities DB = new MachineShopDBEntities();
        var SPresult = DB.GetSingleUser(id).FirstOrDefault();
        return Json(SPresult);
    }
```

Here is my Script:

```
   $("#UserSelect").change(function () {
        $.post("/MenuMaster/GetSingleUser?id=" + $(this).val(),
                function (data, status) {
                    var databaseString = data.MenuEnable;
                    for (i = 0; i <= databaseString.length; i++) {
                        if (databaseString.substring(i, i + 1) == "1") {
                            $('.jstree-container-ul li[data-id=' + (i + 1) + ']').find('.jstree-anchor').addClass('jstree-clicked');
                        }
                    }    
                });
    });
```

Comment: @Niharika, @Azaz, please tell me what's the `#UserSelect` , is this checkbox id or any else?
what `GetSingleUser` method's does?

Comment: It is dropdown id and it will returning a string based on that string i will find the index of that string and if we found 1 then that index and jstree data-id will be match then we have to check that checbox this type of logic is in success .

Comment: means if item selected in dropdown is matched with jsTree checkbox then the `jstree-clicked` class will be applied right?

Comment: Yes but only that particular checkbox right now i am facing problem that parent is check then its child will be automatically selected.

Comment: ok could you please provide me sample data is in text format for dropdown and jsTree so I'll try to prepare answer for you

Comment: Drop-down is binding from ajax call And after selection of drop-down i have to do this which i have given in this code and how can i give you sample of the code?

Comment: try to get those data from `console.log()`

Comment: Okay wait let me give you the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178438/discussion-between-azaz-khan-and-ershoaib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created demo for you.

Make changes according to code snippet below

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.menux').jstree({

            "core": { "check_callback": false },

            "checkbox": { "keep_selected_style": false, "three_state": false, "tie_selection": false, "whole_node": false, },

            "plugins": ["checkbox"]

        }).bind("ready.jstree", function (event, data) {

            $(this).jstree("open_all");
            
        }).on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function (e, data) {

            var currentNode = data.node;

            var parent_node = $(".menux").jstree().get_node(currentNode).parents;

            if (data.node.state.checked)
                $(".menux").jstree().check_node(parent_node[0]);
            else
                $(".menux").jstree().uncheck_node(parent_node[0]);
        })

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />



<div class="menux">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Root node 1
            <ul>
                <li data-id="1"><a href="#" >Child node 1</a> </li>
                <li data-id="2"><a href="#" >Child node 2</a></li>
                <li data-id="3"><a href="#" >Child node 3</a></li>
                <li data-id="4"><a href="#" >Child node 4</a></li>
                <li data-id="24"><a href="#" >Child node 24</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

First make sure you have disable `three-state` while initializing `jsTree` as mentioned in above code snippet.

Try to implement above `$('.menux li').each` function in your code.
The below code is only sample to where you have to put this `$('.menux li').each`.

```
$("#UserSelect").change(function () {
        $.post("/MenuMaster/GetSingleUser?id=" + $(this).val(),
            function (data, status) {
                var databaseString = data.MenuEnable;

                $('.menux li').each(function (index, value) {

                    var node = $(".menux").jstree().get_node(this.id);

                    var id = node.data.id;

                    for (i = 0; i <= databaseString.length; i++) {

                        if (databaseString.substring(i, i + 1) == "1") {

                            if ((i + 1) == id) {

                                $(".menux").jstree().check_node(this.id);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

If you got any error like `jsTree is not a function` then you can replace above `$('.menux li').each` function with this

```
$('.menux li').each(function (index, value) {

            for (i = 0; i <= databaseString.length; i++) {

                if (databaseString.substring(i, i + 1) == "1") {

                    var dataid = $('#' + this.id).data('id');

                    if ((i + 1) == dataid) {

                        $('#' + this.id).find('.jstree-anchor').addClass('jstree-clicked');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Azaz khan, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: Hey! Some How your code is right but the tree functionality i don't want to stop.And i want to do this after dropdown selection.can you tell me if it is possible.- @ershoaib

Comment: I'll update the answer soon...I'll let you know about this

Comment: @Azaz khan, view edit section in answer and try to implement at your side :)

Comment: so in my case tree functionality will be disable.right?if i want to automatically check parent then it will be not possible in my case right?  @ershoaib

Comment: I didn't get you what you said but if you have to automatically check parent also then make `three-state` enabled while initializing jsTree. Its all game of `three-state`

Comment: That I know but the problem is if parent is checked from our condition then other menus i mean children will automatically selected.so in this condition will not work properly i mean this line :   if ((i + 1) == id) {

                                $(".menux").jstree().check_node(this.id);
                            }
if three_state is true

Comment: means if you checked parent then it will also automatically check its children  right? but from my side its not happen

Comment: if u set  three_state is true in our code then output will be changed in case of checkbox checked.so if you know how to do it with  three_state is true.? :(

Comment: First tell me you don't want to check children if its parent checked, or vice versa right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178588/discussion-between-azaz-khan-and-ershoaib).

Comment: Hello!! are you there? @ershoaib

Comment: hey @ershoaib Need your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071292/this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer-vsts

Comment: hi @ershoaib i have a question

Comment: @Azazkhan, Sorry friend, m not available till 15th Sep. bcoz m on trip with family :)

Comment: Okay sir Anayway Enjoy :)

Comment: Is It Possible to set JSTree In Horizontal View?

Comment: did u try to modify css? it can be possible by modifying css

Comment: inspect css for jsTree in browser and try to change each value one by one

Comment: Is there any another way?

Comment: i searched so far on google for you but can't found any possible solution...just try on google or modify css. If i found then I'll notify you :)

Comment: Thank you so much :) @ershoaib

Comment: Hello are you there?

Comment: @Azazkhan, yes are you facing any problem?